# Swift compiler issues

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

Hi All,

I am getting a compiler issues as per the screenshot. Can anyone help me to sort out these issues ? Really appreciate. This application runs on swift4 and recently updated the pods as well. After this only I am getting those errors. I tried the suggestions as well but it didn't help me.

Comment: Uh...The function required a handler closure? It already said there in the error. Probably you should handle it via the closure not by assigning to variable

Comment: Can u explain bit more please ? I am not getting what u meant by. I am bit new to swift programming.

Comment: Please search on how to use completion closure in Swift, it's really hard to explain when you yourself don't know what you are doing, it's just simply follow the code completion there and move the other code below into the closure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using this code is enough to get current registration token

```
InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
  if let error = error {
    print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
  } else if let result = result {
    print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
  }
}
```

[According to firebase documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#access_the_registration_token), it is said that you should avoid calling .getToken(authorizedEntity, scope) unless there is a need to enable multiple senders